# Gnuplot PNGs appear black with background set to transparent

Tags: image, png, gnuplot

I'm trying to generate PNGs with transparent backgrounds using gnuplot 4.2. However, the background appears black instead of white and is not transparent in other viewers. The background is white when I generate jpegs, gifs or emfs instead. I'm using Windows 7.

Here's the code snippet I used:

```
set terminal png size 600,600 transparent truecolor
set style data points
set xyplane at 000;
set output "image.png"
splot "data1.txt" using 1:3:5 title ""    
unset output
```

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: You're doing it right.  It works for me on linux.  The white background with jpegs is expected (they don't support transparency).  I would expect the gifs to have a transparent background (if you used `trasparent` in `set terminal`).  What viewers have you tried?  Are you sure the viewer's default background isn't black?  The only other thing that I can think of is you're version of libgd doesn't support transparency (at least the gnuplot wants it to).

Comment: can you try `set terminal pngcairo transparent ...`